# Static images not appearing in OpenLayers 3?

Tags: openlayers

I am developing an application using OpenLayers 3 with a choice of base layer, overlay layer, and feature (vector) layer, and it seems to be going well. You can see the prototype system at http://mapping4ops.org/ShowMaps/M4OPS-index.html. Switching base layers, overlay layers, and vector layers work OK.

I now want to add two images (dated 1764 and 1847) as overlay layer options.

I have georeferenced these images in QGIS using the georeferencer plugin, and they both look good in QGIS. However when I try to load them in OpenLayers 3 they are not appearing. One of the images I reduced in size with GDAL JPEG compression, and the other I chose the LZW compression option. I used Filezilla to copy the files to my web server.

I have checked the extents,and everything else I can think of, as well as put in console.log statements to try and examine the layer in detail, but I cannot get either image to appear at all. All the previous layers I have added (tiled and vector) have worked fine.

There are no errors flagged in the console.

To make diagnosis easier I have created a very simple one layer map for the 1747 image, and this shows the same lack of image. You can see it at http://mapping4ops.org/ShowMaps/testing/Static%20Image.html.

I am fairly new to the geo world.

Comment: i can't see anything on 'static image.html' page

Comment: @Shahzad Bacha I have updated the static image.html' page to highlight the issue is that the map is not appearing, and to list the js script.

Comment: I have now abandoned my attempt to use static images.  Maybe I misunderstood what is possible.  I have instead started to use MapTiler and TileServer to serve the images as tiles - and this works fine.